Run Python3 script from a laravel application and open browser page
Goal: Automating Open browser and the process of filling in login credentials on a login form using site login credentials.
1st I wrote the python3 script login_script.py and when I hit from the terminal
$ python3 login_script.py it's working correctly without any issues but then I hit the same script from my Laravel it's not working.
My Python Code is:
login_script.py
    import subprocess
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time

    # Install Selenium if not already installed
    try:
        import selenium
    except ImportError:
        print("Installing Selenium...")
        subprocess.run(['pip', 'install', 'selenium'])

    # Define your credentials and login URL
    username = 'myusername'
    password = 'mypassword'
    login_url = 'https://example.com/login'

    # Create a WebDriver instance (assuming Chrome)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Maximize the browser window
    driver.maximize_window()

    # Navigate to the login page
    driver.get(login_url)

    # Wait for the page to load (you might need to adjust the time depending on the page load time)
    #time.sleep(1)

    # Find the username and password input fields and fill them in
    username_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
    password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")

    username_field.send_keys(username)
    password_field.send_keys(password)

    # Submit the form
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Optionally, you might want to add some delay here to allow time for the page to load

    # Wait for the login process to complete
    time.sleep(999999999)  # Adjust as needed

    # Close the browser session
    #driver.quit()

My Laravel Code is:
PythonController.php
    <?php

    namespace Modules\SideMenuBuilder\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;


    class PythonController extends Controller
    {
        public function openBrowser(Request $request)
        {
            try {

            // Case 1:
                $basePath = base_path();
                $process = new Process(['python3', base_path() . '/open_browser.py']);
                $process->run();
                return $process->getOutput();

            // Case 2:
                // Activate virtual environment
                $activate_command = 'source pythonenv/bin/activate';
                // Run Python script within the activated virtual environment';
                $python_command = 'python3 open_browser.py';
                // Combine commands with && to execute sequentially
                $command = "$activate_command && $python_command 2>&1";
                // Execute the command and capture output
                $output = shell_exec($command);
                // Output the result
                return response()->json(['output' => $output]);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return response()->json(['output' => $e->getMessage()]);
            }
            //exit();
        }
    }

Can you guide me as to why the browser does not open when I hit the .py file from Laravel and shows a blank page without any error?

What do you mean by "it's not working"? Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a Python problem?

did you confirm that it actually hit the py file?

If not possible with Laravel and Python then we can accept logic with Laravel and javascript or typescript what's why

Yes it's hitting because if I remooved all code from .py and added only print like print("Hello, World from Python!") then it's showing but the above py code is not working with Laravel but it also working from terminal $ python3 login_script.py
